# Develop a flask web application that display the extracted data from twitter

Tags: python, html, css, flask, web-applications

I am developing a dashboard in which i want to display the data in tabular format i.e, extracted from website like twitter every hour

I expect the output to be displayed in the content section of the dashboard.

Comment: Good luck with your project, but what is your specific question?

Comment: I want to display the tweets extracted from twitter in the dashboard content section using Flask python

Comment: Unluckily Stack Overflow is not a place where you place a wish for a software. Here it is expected that you do your best to solve your problem on your own and when you get stuck, you post your code with a proper description of your problem and a specific question.